# Unable to `make clean`: "No rule to make target ...Plo"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, configure, autotools, automake

## Question Summary

I'm trying to `make clean` and I'm getting the following output:

```
Makefile:835: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-bar.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:836: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-baz.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:837: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-qux.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:838: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-quux.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:839: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-quuz.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:840: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-corge.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:841: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-grault.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:842: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-garply.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:843: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-waldo.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:844: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-fred.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:845: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-plugh.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:846: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-xyzzy.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:847: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-babble.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:848: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-thud.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:848: /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-flarp.Plo: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/absolute/path/to/server/server/example/.deps/libfoo-flarp.Plo'. Stop.
```

How can I successfully do a `make clean`? I don't understand what these `.Plo` files are, and they are usually something I don't mess with.

## Investigation

### My Makefile.am

The `Makefile.am` which is used to generate the Makefile from which I'm trying to run the `clean` contains this preamble:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/server/include.am
include $(top_srcdir)/server/tests/include.am
...
```

The first `$(top_srcdir)/server/include.am` includes the following:

```
...
server_libdir = $(exec_prefix)/lib
serverdir = $(top_srcdir)/server
...
```

and in the specified `$(top_srcdir)/server/tests/include.am`, I have a lot of things including:

```
...
server_lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/bar.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/baz.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/qux.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/quux.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/quuz.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/corge.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/grault.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/garply.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/waldo.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/fred.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/plugh.c \
    /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/xyzzy.c \
    ...
```

### Investigating the `Makefile` Contents

If I look at the `Makefile` directly and find the lines generating these errors, I see the following:

```
include /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-bar.Plo
include /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-baz.Plo
include /absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-qux.Plo
...
```

### Where are the .Plo files generated?

Frustratingly, there seems to be the exact `.Plo` files that I need generated all over the place, just not in the right place; for example these files exist:

```
/absolute/path/to/server/tests/absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-bar.Plo
/absolute/path/to/server/tests/absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-baz.Plo
/absolute/path/to/server/tests/absolute/path/to/server/server/example/$(DEPDIR)/libfoo-qux.Plo
...
```

and there are 7 other directories where these `.Plo` files are created.

## Unsuccessful Attempts

### Running `config.status` directly

I found [this message on the GNU mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2002-04/msg00059.html):

> Actually, these *.P* files are created by config.status for each
> directory it creates an Automake Makefile in. (BTW, make sure
> `./config.status --help' lists the relevant Makfiles in the` Configuration files' section).
>
> You can request the creation of the *.P* files for a given directory
> by running
>
> % rm -Rf kernel/framework/.deps
> % ./config.status kernel/framework/Makefile depfiles

And ran `./config.status` as described but the output of `make clean` hasn't changed

According to [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192620/regenerate-plo-files-without-running-configure), they were able to generate .Plo files, but I don't know what is different for them.

Comment: Your `clean` rule is not right.  `clean` shouldn't require any other files to exist: its entire point is to clean things up not create things.  However, there's nothing we can do with the information given here.  What is in your makefile at the lines shown in the error output?  What does your `clean` and `clean-recursive` rules look like?  It seems you're using automake here: what have you set for `clean` in your `Makefile.am` file?

Comment: ok thanks I'll provide this information ASAP. This is a problem that has a bunch of files involved and I didn't know what would be helpful to include

Comment: I haven't modified the `clean` task, from what I understand it should fall back to a premade `clean`, correct?

Comment: Your makefile is broken.  How it got that way is impossible for us to say from the information given.  You could try re`configure`ing the project to make a new one, but whether that helps depends in part on how the current one  got broken.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok I've re`configure`d  but still got the same issue. Now I know there's not a nice solution and that's good enough for me. Maybe I'll git clean to start completely fresh. Is there a possibility that I could provide some information to be able to diagnose further, though?

Comment: If the code is under git source control, then you could consider `git diff`ing the various `Makefile.am` files and any other files that they `include`.  If you have local changes to those then they are a likely place to look for the issue.  If you *don't* have local changes to those, then it may well be that the you inherited the problem from upstream.

Comment: `git clean` didn't work. Also, I can go back to any commit in my git log and I still get this error for this target, but there were times where this target could be built. Maybe my .gitignore ignores something it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-run `configure` with the `--disable-dependency-tracking` option