# Old .Po file references old directory, how to start fresh?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, configure, autotools, automake

## Introduction

I just deleted the directory `nested` and removed the reference to it in my `Makefile.am`

I'm running `./configure && make` and I get the following:

```
*** No rule to make target 'nested/main.c', needed by 'main.o'. Stop.
```

How can I run `make` so that it doesn't reference old directories?

### Supplemental Info

I was curious if I could find where this reference is, so I did a `grep -r nested .` I think the only relevant hit is:

```
./src/.deps/main.Po:main.o nested/main.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h /usr/include/stdio.h \
```

Comment: I would try `autoreconf` before `configure` and `make clean`. If that fails to help, then I would try `find . -type d -name '.deps'` and remove those '.deps' directories. If that fails to help, I would consider what `git clean -n -d -x` shows and maybe after committing/stashing/saving/backing up all important files actually run `git clean`.

Comment: Another thing to try would be an out-of-source build.  Create a new, empty directory, make that the working directory, and run `<path>/<to>/configure` to get started.  All Autotools-based projects should understand that, though not all of them support it properly.

Comment: And I would actually suggest that you *avoid* `autoreconf` unless your project distribution fails to provide its normal outputs (`Makefile.in` files, `aclocal.m4`, support scripts, ...).  If you do need to run it -- or if you want to try that as a last resort --  then make sure you use its `-i` and `-f` options, and pay careful attention to any warnings (or errors) it emits.

Comment: I did an out-of-source build and got: `configure:error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first` so I did that and was able to build. I'm not sure if I only needed to `make distclean`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If someone has edited `Makefile.am`, wouldn't running `autoreconf` with some suitable set of parameters being the logical next step?

Comment: Yes, @ndim, but the recommendation to avoid `autoreconf` was predicated on the supposition that the upstream autotools inputs have not been modified, which is consistent with my evaluation of the situation.  I probably should have been more clear about that. In such a case, it is preferable to use the upstream-generated build system *in toto* -- this is the usage model around which the autotools are designed, and it avoids issues that sometimes arise when different versions of the autotools are used than the build system was developed for.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought the original question was "I removed this directory from the filesystem and removed its mention from `Makefile.am`". I thought removing the mention of the directory from `Makefile.am` means the autotools inputs have already been modified.

Comment: Good point, @ndim.  I probably did not read this question carefully, because I am interpreting it in light of [the OP's previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73196951/unable-to-make-clean-no-rule-to-make-target-plo).

Comment: Ah, OK. I did not really read OP's previous question as I found it too long and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this question from OP's comment:

Run

```
make distclean
```